# Activity with few images works slow on phones

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, imageview

I've seen other similar posts, which didn't solve my problem because the resolutions of my images are small (see bottom) compared to theirs. I want an activity in which I list imageviews like it was a listview. But since I didnt understand how to do it in Listview, I decided to do it with gridview and one element per column. Here my code - It's mostly copied from the example developer.android.com gives us, except that I stretch the width of my grid to the width of the screen:

```
public class ImageAdap extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

private int widthDisplay;

public ImageAdap(Context c, int width) { //int width is the width of the display in pixel
    mContext = c;
    widthDisplay = width;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    int height = widthDisplay * 3 / 4;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(widthDisplay, height));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sampleda_01,
        R.drawable.sampleda_02,
        R.drawable.sampleda_03,
        R.drawable.sampleda_04 
};  }
```

The code works fluently on my 8' tablet (I also tested on 10' virtual device and it also worked fine). But on two different phones and on two virtual devices of ~5 inch it lagged like hell.

My images have resolution 800x640. I also tested on 600x480 (the quality of the images is also worst with like 90kb each) -> all same result. It seems like the resolution of the images doesn't matter for my problem. But since it works fine with tablets: My tablet is old compared to a phone I tested on, so the used hardware also shouldn't be the source of the problem.

I designed the app in 4.1 and tested on 4.4 and 6.0 on virtual devices and on 5.0 and dunno which version with phones -> The API shouldn't be the problem, too.

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement ViewHolder pattern. That must increase productivity. 
Here is a nice example of how to do that: 
[click](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

And why does your 'getItem()' method return 'null'?

Comment: I'm watching a tutorial about that, will test it afterwards and reply as soon as possible.

Comment: thanks for the link. about getItem() I dont know and also no clue what it's for. But I have a problem including ViewHolder for this line: imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

Comment: @calumon the getItem() method is so you don't have to call directly into an array or collection in getView(). The idea is that you would instead have `@DrawableRes public int getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}` or something along those lines.

Comment: @Cliabhach I see, thanks. Still, it didnt like the ViewHolder. Seems like I'm doing some things wrong.

Comment: @frozzyk after hours of trying, I give up :/ Didn't get it working. Dunno what's my mistake

Comment: @calumon watch this [Android performance patterns episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA). That may help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the save problem,and I add `android:largeHeap="true"`in my AndroidManifest.xml and then it works better. but I'm not sure whether the same reason cause the problem